# Multithreading and events

Tags: c#, multithreading, dotnet-httpclient

I have some problems with multithreading and events.

I have the following function which executes in a few threads:

```
private void GetProjectInformation(object obj)
{
    //Casten
    //string projectName = (string)obj;
    FilterOptions filter = (FilterOptions)obj;

    ProjectConnectionManager connectionManager = new ProjectConnectionManager();
    connectionManager.GetProjectInfo(filter);
    connectionManager.InfoReceived += delegate(object sender, ProjectInfoEventArgs e)
    {
        //Geupdate resultaat in de collection vervangen
        int index = 0;
        bool found = false;
        m_dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() =>
        {
            foreach (ProjectInfo projectInfo in m_allProjects)
            {
                if (String.Equals(projectInfo.ProjectName, e.ProjectInfo.ProjectName))
                {
                    found = true;
                    ProjectInfo result = e.ProjectInfo;   
                    m_allProjects[index] = e.ProjectInfo;

                    break;
                }
                index++;
            }

            //Niet gevonden
            if (!found)
            {
                m_allProjects.Add(e.ProjectInfo);
            }
        }));
    };
}
```

It gets called like this:

```
foreach (FilterOptions opt in m_projectsToShow)
{
    Thread thread = 
                 new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(GetProjectInformation));
    thread.Start(opt);
}
```

The problem I am facing (I Think), is that after

```
connectionManager.GetProjectInfo(filter);
```

my thread cancels. I am getting an AggregateException which tells me that a task has been closed, so I guess that this have to be the problem. What I would like to achieve is the following. My function, so the current thread, has to block until that event has been fired:

```
connectionManager.InfoReceived += ...
```

Is there any solution to this? Can you give me some code please?

Edit:

This is the GetProjectInfo method:

```
public void GetProjectInfo(FilterOptions filter)
    {
        ProjectInfo result = new ProjectInfo();

        try
        {
            var task = m_httpClient.PostAsync(string.Format("api/project"), new ObjectContent<FilterOptions>(filter, XmlMediaTypeFormatter.DefaultMediaType));
            task.ContinueWith(r =>
            {
                try
                {
                    r.Wait();
                    if (r.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Project " + filter.ProjectName + " was succesfull...");

                        r.Result.Content.ReadAsAsync<ProjectInfo>().ContinueWith(l =>
                        {
                            result = l.Result;
                            OnProjectInfoReceived(new ProjectInfoEventArgs(result));
                        });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Project " + filter.ProjectName + " failed!");
                    }
                }
                catch (AggregateException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                }
            }).Wait(m_httpClient.Timeout);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

And I get the AggregateException in there.

This is the exception:

```
System.AggregateException was caught
  Message=One or more errors occurred.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
       at Dashboard.Utils.ProjectConnectionManager.<>c__DisplayClass8.<GetProjectInfo>b__5(Task`1 r) in C:\Users\xxx\Documents\My Own Documents\xxx\ProjectConnectionManager.cs:line 79
  InnerException: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException
       Message=A task was canceled.
       InnerException:
```

Comment: `m_allProjects` should better be a thread-safe collection.

Comment: Does `GetProjectInfo()` start another thread somehow? Otherwise you should hook up the event first.

Comment: Thanks Henk, I should have a look at that as well. But I first would like to have a solution to my main problem :)

Comment: I edited the question and I added the GetProjectsInfo method, which contains a task itself (async). I tried to hook up the event first and then call GetProjectInformation() but the problem remains.

Comment: I updated my post with the exception too. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`AggregateExceptions` are thrown by `Tasks`, but you are using `Threads` ??

Anyway, to block the thread until the event handler has run, you can use a `ManualResetEvent`:

```
private void GetProjectInformation(object obj)
{
    ...
    ProjectConnectionManager connectionManager = new ProjectConnectionManager();

    var mre = new ManualResetEvent( false );

    connectionManager.InfoReceived += delegate( ... )
    {
        ...
        mre.Set();
    };

    connectionManager.GetProjectInfo(filter);

    mre.WaitOne();
}
```

Comment: I tried this solution but it does not work. What else could be wrong then?

Comment: Somehow I could solve the problem by putting the .Continue on 1 line and not in a new line like I did first. Very weird situation. Thank you all anyway !!